# How to measure a while loop iteration average with Stopwatch

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I need to know how long (in average), it takes for a single message to be sent to the queue, so I sent 1000 and then split the total by 1000 t get an average.

However this console app takes about 5-10 minutes and at the end the total milliseconds its a very weird number, like 100 or 400. And the division is always 0. I literally took my handwatch and the app takes between 5 to 10 minutes

What I am doing wrong to measure this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string queueConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
            QueueClient queueClientEmpresa = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(queueConnectionString, "CapatechSaasApp");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Testing sending millions of messages");
                int i = 0;
                // Create new stopwatch
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

                // Begin timing
                stopwatch.Start();
                while (i < 1000)
                {
                    Empresa empresa = new Empresa()
                    {
                        Nombre = "Empresa:" + i,
                        NIT = "xx",
                        NombreRepresentanteLegal = "xx",
                        TelefonoRepresentanteLegal = "xx",
                        NombreContacto = "x",
                        TelefonoContacto = "x"
                    };
                    i++;

                    BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empresa));
                    message.Properties.Add("Operation", "Add");
                    message.Properties.Add("Tipo", "Empresa");
                    queueClientEmpresa.Send(message);

                    //string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
                    //Console.WriteLine("Press key to continue");
                    //Console.ReadKey();
                    //ReceiveMessagesEmpresa(connectionString);                  
                }
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed milliseconds: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed milliseconds/1000: {0}", (stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds/1000).ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

http://screencast.com/t/fjcFRbf2jM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TimeSpan` has various properties, and you're not using the right one :-)

`MilliSeconds` is the milliseconds part of the whole timespan.
`TotalMilliSeconds` is the whole time, expressed as milliseconds.

Use `TotalMilliseconds`.

P.S. You could also use `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` which is identical.

Comment: Hi @EstebanV,  as the answer Amit gave you fits your needs, shouldn't you mark it as accepted answer... ?

Comment: yes but you have to wait some minutes before you can accept an answer so quick